# Angular 5 - Load in child component dynamically into parent's view using ng-content

Tags: angular

I am working on a web application which will have multiple "apps".
Each app consists of a workflow containing 1 or more views. Only 1 view is visible at a time and the only 2 things that each view has in common is that they have **a content pane and a footer bar**, and all views share **the same data workset**. The idea behind this is that it is possible to do "customer specific" overrides during run-time of views, or add additional custom views to the workflows.

For the apps I created a `BaseComponent` which will handle the initial loading, the view transitions and some other stuff which I left out of the example.
The apps, which are components themselves, extend on this `BaseComponent` and pass on a list of views in the `super()` method.

---

**Custom App component** - Our custom app, we will have loads of these

```
// Example list of views. Each view is an object containing an id and a component.
const views = [view1, view2, view3, ...]; 

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-app',
  templateUrl: '../base/base.component.html'
})
export class CustomAppComponent extends BaseComponent {
  constructor() {
    super(views); // Load in the views into the BaseComponent
  }
}
```

**Base component** - The basic of each app, should handle all the magic

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './base.component.html'
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver;
  private views: AppView[];
  workset: AppWorkset;

  @ViewChild(ViewHostDirective)
  private viewHost: ViewHostDirective;

  constructor(views: AppView[] = []) {
    // Custom injector to be able to inject directly inject them 
    // without having to pass on in the super method
    const injector = AppInjector.get(); 

    this.componentFactoryResolver = injector.get<ComponentFactoryResolver>(<any>ComponentFactoryResolver);

    this.workset = new AppWorkset();
    this.workset.nextView = (id) => this.nextView(id);
    this.views = views;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Load the first view
    this.nextView(Views.First);
  }

  nextView(id: number) {
    const view = this.views.find(v => v.id === id);
    if (view == null) {
      console.log('No view with id', id);
      return;
    }

    // Clear the current view
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(view.component);
    const viewContainerRef = this.viewHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    // Update the viewHost with the new component that will serve as our new view
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    // Pass on our shared workset
    (<AppViewComponent>componentRef.instance).workset = this.workset;
  }
}
```

**View Host directive** - Directive to be able to change the view during run-time with a new component

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[view-host]',
})
export class ViewHostDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

**Base component's html**

```
<h3>My app</h3>
<ng-template view-host></ng-template>
```

**Example of a view** - All views will have their own custom logic, they only share a workset

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <h4>First view</h4>

    <button (click)="next()">Next view</button>
  `
})
class FirstView implements AppViewComponent {
  @Input() workset: AppWorkset;

  next() {
    this.workset.nextView(Views.Second);
  }
}
```

---

Now this all works perfectly fine. The more difficult part I want to achieve is to have a default "html template" in which the views are going to rendered. This is what I first mentioned about each view having a content pane and a footer bar. See the simple example below.

[image: Example of content pane and footer bar]

In addition I have some functionality that checks the `#appcontent` content's changes, so it can apply some correct sizing (scrollbar, etc). The idea of having a "magic" base component, is to keep the apps and their views itself so simple as possible, thus this "html template" should be a part of the base as well. Normally to achieve such a thing you could use ng-content to split up the child's html to the right places when it gets added to the parent's.

```
<div class="my-content-css" #appcontent>
  <ng-content select=".app-content"></ng-content>
</div>

<div class="my-footer-css" #appfooter>
  <ng-content select=".app-footer"></ng-content>
</div>
```

But in this case I can't get it to work, as the `<ng-template view-host></ng-template>` will put the view's content in a `ng-component` element and so neither `ng-content` nor `ngTemplateOutlet` will parse this correctly.

---

[To give hands-on about my situation I made the example in stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-view-loading)